# the difference between "in respect to" and "with respect to"

Tags: prepositions

What is the difference between "*with* respect to" or "*in* respect to" ?

Comment: Can you provide some more context.  That is firstly show the dictionary definitions you are using.  Secondly give examples of using the phrases in context. Finally, try to explain why you are confused.  Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't really need more context - one is right, the other is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase is 'with respect to'.

'In respect to' is just wrong. It is a mix between 'in respect of' and 'with respect to'.

See [ELU: "In respect of" / "With respect to"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/123274/in-respect-of-with-respect-to)  and the [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/with-respect-to-in-respect-of)

Comment: Right for sure. in respect of tends to be more British.

Answer (score -1):

"in respect to" most often means "about" or "concerning" or something similar, depending on context. It is a little unusual. "With respect" usually is a way of politely acknowledging another person, particularly one with authority. It can be sincere or ironic. But context could m,ake a large difference in either phrase.

Comment: OP typoed the body, the title refers to "respect to" in both versions, which makes this well off the mark. Personally, I'd always call 'in respect to' plain wrong. I found https://english.stackexchange.com/a/123288/99969 which agrees with me, as does [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/with-respect-to-in-respect-of) albeit less distinctly.